# How to solve "Could not find any Python installation to use" with docker node alpine Image when adding bcrypt to package.json?

Tags: python, node.js, docker, bcrypt, alpine-linux

Before I added bcrypt to my package.json, everything was working fine. Now, I get the error message below.

This is an excerpt of my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "3.0.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.3.0",
    "pm2": "^3.5.1",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.0"
  },
```

This is my dockerfile. I am using the offical node alpine image. I wonder if alpine has phyton already installed.

```
FROM node:13.5.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./src .

RUN npm install
```

I get this error message when I run docker-compose:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.6/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.6-node-v79-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.6 and node@13.5.0 (node-v79 ABI, musl) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:179:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:309:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:321:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:305:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-47-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/usr/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v79"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/app/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v13.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/usr/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v79' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/app/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:305:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-47-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/app/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/app/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v13.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/usr/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v79' (1)
npm WARN testapp@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-12-24T14_22_05_060Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How can I solve this issue? Do I have to install phyton on alpine or just add the env variable? If so, please tell me how. I have already searched for solutions but no one worked ...

Comment: People like the Alpine base images because they're very small; because they're very small, they don't contain things like language interpreters that you don't explicitly install.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the sake of completeness: I solved it.

The solution was to replace the dependency "bcrypt" with "bcrypt**js**".

With bcryptjs there are no errors. Neither with standard node docker images nor node alpine docker images.

Answer (score 75):

Add this in you docker file before npm install:

```
RUN apk add --update python make g++\
   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

If you're working with Python 3, remember to use **python3** instead of python.

Comment: This is the correct answer actually. npm builds native packages and node-gyp is dependent on python. Additionally, you can use multistage build if you don't really want those build tools in the final image. https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: I think this one should be the accepted answer because if it works on alpine images there wouldn't be a need to use bulky node images unnecessarily. But currently this is failing for me using node:14-alpine version.

Comment: python2 has been discontinued, so only option is to use python3 now

Answer (score 44):

Open Powershell with administrator privileges and run this command, then proceed with bcrypt installation

Windows: `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

Comment: this is only applicable to windows

Answer (score 32):

Linux Alpine is very minimalist image. If performance is not a restriction, you may want to consider using the **official node image** that has all the dependencies you need and just worry about development: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node
So, you can have a **Dockerfile** like this:

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY ./src .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000 # Use here the port you want to expose
```

Comment: Not the most optimal, but probably the easiest to apply answer

Answer (score 16):

Compose file to run node server in Dockerfile

```html
FROM node:16.8.0-alpine
ENV SERVER_HOME=/usr/src/server/
WORKDIR $SERVER_HOME
COPY ./package*.json $SERVER_HOME
RUN npm install -g npm@7.24.0
RUN apk add --update python3 make g++ && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN npm install
COPY . $SERVER_HOME
#EXPOSE 5000
CMD npm run build
CMD npm run start
```

I faced an issue in installing the node module in the alpine image so python is not found in alpine so I run this with python3
RUN apk add --update python3 make g++ && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
everything worked fine if you still face issue replace npm install with
npm install --force

Answer (score 15):

Correct solution for Alpine would be

```
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 make g++
```

Answer (score 6):

I have resolved this just by downloading and installing python from
https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was with pg-native dependency using node-gyp incorrectly.

Found the solution from this link - [node-gyp failure pg-native](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/223)

Extract from the comment that helped:

> A: Don't use two different db libraries by accident: i.e. pg and pg.js.

> B: Be cautious using things like sequelize that you may have flagged the 'native' option in initializing your connection to the DB. This will also often cause this error.

> C: Lastly, I often remove the pg-native library entirely. Causes strange errors that are not consistent with node-gyp.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue today and ended up switching from alpine to bookworm:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:20-bookworm
```

It's not worth the headache to force it with alpine docker image when debian will work without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this error only changing the image of node:

From this:

```
# build stage
FROM node:18-alpine as build-stage
...
```

To this:

```
# build stage
FROM node:18 as build-stage
...
```